# Bootstrap : my dropdown menu in navbar doesn't toggle again after item selection in toggled menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 'standard' test nav bar from Bootstrap example, however using active_links gem 
navbar =>   Brand - About - Page1 - Page2 - Pages ( Page3 - Page4 - more..)

when I click 'Pages' , the dropdown open, and I can click on Page3, (Page4, ...)
but in Page3 if I click again on 'Pages' the dropdown doesn't toggle anymore... I have to click on another navbar item ( About, Page1 or Page2 ) to be able again to toggle the dropdown

no existing css related to the navbar ( standard Bootstrap3 )

my navbar

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-default{:role => "navigation"}
/ -- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display
.navbar-header
    %button.navbar-toggle{ :type => "button", :'data-toggle' => "collapse", :'data-target' => ".navbar-ex1-collapse"}
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
        %span.icon-bar
    = active_link_to "o-MobileServer", root_path, :class => "navbar-brand"

/ -- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
.collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse
    %ul.nav.navbar-nav
        %li= active_link_to 'About', page_path("about"), :wrap_tag => :li
        %li= active_link_to 'Page1', page_path("page1"), :wrap_tag => :li
        %li= active_link_to 'Page2', page_path("page2"), :wrap_tag => :li

        %li.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{:'data-toggle' => :dropdown}
                = "Pages"   
                %b.caret
            %ul.dropdown-menu{:role => "menu"}
                %li= active_link_to 'Page3', page_path("page3"), :wrap_tag => :li
                %li= active_link_to 'Page4', page_path("page4"), :wrap_tag => :li
                %li= active_link_to 'Page5', page_path("page5"), :wrap_tag => :li
                %li.divider
                %li.nav-header
                    %b= "More Pages"
                %li= active_link_to 'Page6', page_path("page6"), :wrap_tag => :li
                %li= active_link_to 'Page7', page_path("page7"), :wrap_tag => :li
```

what could be wrong ?  should I add a specific css ?
tahnks for help

---

Running Bootstrap 3 / Rails 4

I commented in application.js

// require turbolinks

and the problem disappeared ... need further investigation

Answer (score 0):

so real answer , was given in post :

[Rails 4 Turbolinks make form submit multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068951/rails-4-turbolinks-make-form-submit-multiple-times/18074228#18074228)

I did not noticed that application.js was called from within my %body
moved it to %head, now running perfectly...