# Rails 4.2 - performance issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have recently updated one of my apps to `Rails 4.2`. When running on my local machine I have noticed that a simple `link_to` to a basic show action sometimes takes a very long time to complete.

Here is the link:

```
= link_to team_members_path(@team) do
  Members
```

Here is my action (in my `MembersController`):

```
def index

  @team = Team.find_by_id(params[:team_id])

  if params[:search].present?
    @members = Member.search ThinkingSphinx::Query.escape(params[:search]), :with => {:team_id => @team.id}, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  else
    @members = Member.search params[:search], :with => {:team_id => @team.id}, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
  end
end
```

I use `Sphinx` and `ThinkingSphinx` for search. When clicking the link I get an unusual long "log" in my console.

```
Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2014-12-24 11:24:40 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
[renders stuff etc]

...

Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2014-12-24 11:24:40 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
[renders stuff etc. with the same timestamp as above]

...

Started GET "/users/1" for ::1 at 2014-12-24 11:24:40 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
[renders stuff etc. with the same timestamp as above]
```

This action: `Started GET "/users/1"` seems to get called multiple times as you can see above (way more than what I pasted above), which seems to result in a pretty bad performance, even when running on my local machine.

And I'm not quite sure on how I can solve it or what's causing it. Any ideas?

**Note**

I actually don't know why `GET "/users/1"` get called at all in this case. I'm not linking to the users show action.

I have checked it using the Firefox console. See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like turbolinks gem which was introduced with Rails 4 causing the problem as I can see to many js requests. Try to view show pay directly instead like http://localhost:3000/users/1. You can remove turbolinks if it causing the trouble which meant for performance improvement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068951/rails-4-turbolinks-make-form-submit-multiple-times may help you out.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried to disable turolinks like this: `'data-turbolinks-track' => false`, but I still have the same issue. Any other ideas? I actually don't know why `GET "/users/1"` get called at all in this case. I'm not linking to the users show action.

Comment: Please checking console log with firebug. This way you will know if your web page is actually sending the js requests.

Comment: @maximus Yes, I have done it now and it seems like it's sending the requests. I have added an image from the log to my question.

Comment: @maximus don't think the view will give you any clues tbh.

Comment: it will since ajax requests are originating from view. Try to remove all the code and see if it reproduce.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Seems to be a Javascript / Ajax issue.

Comment: Great, you can answer your own question, which can help others too.

Comment: @maximus Yes, I have now done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with my inline `Javascript` that I had in a partial form (`_form.html.haml`). This form is rendered on most pages since it's placed in a Bootstrap modal window and it can be presented anywhere. In this partial I perform some `Javascript` and `Ajax` calls. Each time the form is rendered I performed this action using `Ajax`:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "#{update_idea_team_path}",
    data: {
      team_id : $('#select_idea_team').val()
    },
    dataType: "script"
  });
```

For some reason this seemed to cause the problem described in my question above. Moving the Javascript and Ajax code to a `.coffee.js` file instead of rendering it inline solved the issue for me.